# Why i am not able to play this Video in to Galaxy Ace but can play it in to Galaxy SII?

Tags: video, device, android, android-video-player

Here is the two video file properties :
[image]

I am playing this video in to both device, Samsung Galaxy Ace and Samsung Galaxy SII.

While i run Alone.mp4 then it play fine for both the device. But as same if i run the Pfront.mp4 video then it only play in to galaxy SII and not play in Galaxy Ace. and that time in Galaxy Ace it gives me message like: Sorry, this video cannot be played.

Is there a Problem with the configuration of the Video File ?
Whats wrong here ? Why i am not able to play the Video in to Galaxy Ace ?

Thanks.

**Edited with code**

I am using below code to play the Video

```
case R.id.playVideoBtn:
        File file2 = new File("/sdcard/Pfront.mp4");
        Uri video = Uri.fromFile(file2);

        myVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
        myVideoView.start();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Using some software like VLC, show us which codec was used in each video.

Comment: I want to implement it for my own application. I am going to update the question with the code. Please wait for it. And yes i dont want any inbuilt application to run it.